# How to get string arraylist from string by filtering single single word from single string in flutter?

Tags: flutter

"phrase": "educated washroom stinging breeze regroup earphone threaten epidemic hazy imbecile fritter bony"

So, phrase is my string.
I want to get phrase string in form of string arraylist

stringList = ['educated','washroom','stinging',....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using split method of string like this

```
const string = 'Hello world!';
final splitted = string.split(' ');
print(splitted); // [Hello, world!];
```

you can read more details about split method from the official [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/split.html).

**Edit:**

The solution for the problem you typed in the comment.

```
 ListView.builder(
          itemCount: stringList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(stringList[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: How can I display this string in list

Comment: 12 words should display as separate item in listview

Comment: checkout the answer now i updated the answer.